# Get a sprites position so that the next sprite can be placed near it

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I am trying to build a simulator inside of Pygame that simulates grass being grown. The purpose of trying to get the position of a current spite (grass) is so that a new sprite (grass) can be added next to it.

First I create a class that gives the pieces of grass a position.

```
class Grass(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self, width, height, pos_x, pos_y, color):
    super().__init__()
    self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
    self.image.fill(color)
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.center = [pos_x, pos_y]
```

Then I add a piece of grass so that we can start the spawning process, I do this by creating a group.

```
grass_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
grass = Grass(20, 20, random.randrange(50, width - 50), random.randrange(50, height - 50), green)
grass_group.add(grass)
grass_group.draw(screen)
```

Then I want to create a new piece of grass every second next to the old bits of grass.

```
    if seconds <= (one_second + 100) and seconds >= (one_second - 100):
    one_second += 1000
    for i in range(len(grass_group)):
        for j in range(len(grass_group)):
            j.x = 
            j.y =
            i.x = random.choice(j.x - 20, j.x, j.x + 20)
            i.y = random.choice(j.y - 20, j.y, j.y + 20)
            i = Grass(20, 20, i.x, i.y, green)
            grass_group.add(i)
            grass_group.draw(screen)
            pygame.display.flip()
```

So I need to find out what the position of all of the old bits of grass is in order to create the new bit of grass near it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The peace of grass should be aligned to the grid. Set the *step* argument when you create a random position:

```py
grass = Grass(20, 20, 
    random.randrange(50, width - 50, 20),
    random.randrange(50, height - 50, 20),
    green)
grass_group.add(grass)
```

First you have to find all the possible grass positions. Implement the following algorithm:

- Iterate through the possible grass positions in a nested loop.
- Test if a grass is at a position by [`pygame.Rect.collidepoint()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint).
- If a grass is at the position, then go t o the next position.
- Test if a grass is next to the position. If a grass is found then add the position to a list.

```py
def isGrass(x, y):
    return any(g for g in grass_group.sprites if g.rect.collidepoint(x, y))

def isNextToGrass(x, y):
    neighbours = [
        (x-20, y-20), (x, y-20), (x+20, y-20), (x-20, y),
        (x+20, y), (x-20, y+20), (x, y+20), (x+20, y+20)]
    return any(pos for pos in neighbours if isGrass(*pos))

def findGrassPositions():
    poslist = []
    for x in range(50, width - 50, 20):
        for y in range(50, height - 50, 20):
            if not isGrass(x, y):
                if isNextToGrass(x, y):
                    poslist.append((x, y))
    return poslist
```

Use the algorithm to find all the possible position for a grass and take a `random.choice` from the list:

```py
if seconds <= (one_second + 100) and seconds >= (one_second - 100):
    one_second += 1000
    allposlist = findGrassPositions()
    if allposlist:
        new_x, new_y = random.choice(allposlist)
        new_grass = Grass(20, 20, new_x, new_y, green)
        grass_group.add(new_grass)
        

grass_group.draw(screen)
pygame.display.flip()
```